# What is the best tool to save a HTML file?

Tags: download, website, css, wysiwyg, xhtml

Suppose I see a HTML page and I want to save it on disk. Using all methods I found, the saved sites are never same as they look in a browser.

So is there any free tool that can be used to save websites? It should also download every file, like CSS, JavaScript and images.

Answer (score 8):

[httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) works well enough that i often use it for converting dynamic websites into static sites for various reasons. Needs a little tweaking to get just right (how deep you want to download, whether you want external files, etc), but in terms of output, its as good as it gets.